# Convert array index into String using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, implode

```
array:5 [▼
  "open" => "info"
  "on_hold" => "warning"
  "answered" => "success"
  "dev. In progress" => "success"
  "closed" => "default"
];
```

I need to use this array and get only the index to String like this

```
'ticket_statuses' => [
    'open' => 'info',
    'on_hold' => 'warning',
    'answered' => 'success',
    'dev. In progress' => 'success',
    'closed' => 'default',
]

$array = config('settings.ticket_statuses');
$status = implode(',', $array);
dd($status);
```

When i using implode($array) result look like this

```
"info,warning,success,success,default"
```

But I don't need this

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: So you want https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to implode the indexes, think you mean `open`, `on_hold`, you need to use the `array_keys()` method:

```
$array = [
    'open' => 'info',
    'on_hold' => 'warning'
];

echo implode(',', array_keys($array)); // echo: open,on_hold
```

Comment: Great! Please accept to answer so it can help others.